# Remove outline from select dropdown (Chrome on Windows 7)

Tags: css, google-chrome, select, windows-7, outline

I am trying to remove a blue outline from the option list of a `select` element.

As I only see this outline on Chrome on Windows 7, here is an image which points out the outline I’m talking about
[image]

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/463pLc67/

I’ve tried using `outline-color` on the `option:focus` as well but it doesn’t seem to have any effect. Is there any way to get rid of this outline just using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Because browsers handle UI aethetics differently for elements like radio buttons, checkboxes and select drop downs it's hard to overcome without using JS or complex CSS/HTML. I think Select elements are even harder than radio buttons and checkboxes, I don't think there is a reliable HTML/CSS only for this.

Sorry, I know this isn;t the answer you're looking for. You could also try 'border: 1px solid #COLOR' as a last ditch attempt.

Comment: Thanks, I tried **a lot** of things but I think the only way around this is to replace the element with JS…

Answer (score 0):

The `appearance: none` rule changes a bit the display (On Ubuntu/Chromium) but makes it more buggy: no right-border but still some left-borders (No effect on firefox).

Normal:

[image]

With `appreance: none`:

[image]

You can play with the `background-color` which works also on `<option>` to make it closer to your outline color so it would hide it a little.

```css
select.lalala option {
  background-color: #727272;
}
```

[image]

Nothing visually acceptable IMHO.

Btw this is browser specific as also probably OS specific so it seems to be a loss of time.